# Getting the long form of an ID in a formula

Tags: formula, salesforce-id

I have a text field which I want to have the default value of the record's ID (I need the long form).
When I use the Id field in the formula I only get the short form (without the object type sufix)
Is there any way I can get the long form Id in the formula?

Comment: The 3 character object code is the prefix, not the suffix. The difference between the 15 and 18 character version is that the 15 character one makes use of mixed case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean the 18 digit Id? You can use CASESAFEID(Id) as a formula to return the 18 digit case insensitive version of the record's Id.